# Python solidworks package module object is not callable

Tags: python

I am trying to use the python solidworks package from https://github.com/mklanac/pySolidWorks
I have written the lines exactly as described in the documentation (see below) but somehow it does not work.

```
# Add pySolidWorks to path
import sys
sys.path.append(r'D:\Python\pySolidWorks-main')


from pysolidworks import Solidworks
sw = Solidworks()
```

Here in the error im getting:

```
runfile('D:/Python/test_solidworks.py', wdir='D:/Python')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File D:\Python\test_solidworks.py:23 in <module>
    sw = Solidworks()

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?